# How to pass a single tuple to a function that expects a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having some issues with assigning my own x and y values for a plot.
By default, x and y are combinations of data frame column names.

For example, var_combinations contains:

`(('Cerebrum Volume', 'Cerebellum Volume'), ('Cerebrum Volume', 'Cerebellum Surface Area'), ('Cerebellum Volume', 'Cerebellum Surface Area'))`

This works great when left alone, see working code below.

```
col_names = [list(data.columns)[4], list(data.columns)[3], list(data.columns)[1]]
var_combinations = tuple(itertools.combinations(col_names, 2))


def create_plot(xy=var_combinations, logged=False):
    if not logged:
        fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(1, (len(xy)), figsize=(16, 5))

        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(xy):
            axs1[i].scatter(data[x], data[y], c=taxon.map(colors), edgecolor='k')
            
            axs1[i].set(
                title=f'Primate {xy[i][0]} against\n{xy[i][1]}',
                xlabel=f'{xy[i][0]}',
                ylabel=f'{xy[i][1]}'
            )
    elif logged: .........

create_plot(var_combinations, logged=False)
```

However I want to be able to enter my own variable names when calling the function, such as:

`create_plot(('Cerebellum Surface Area', 'Cerebrum Volume'), ('etc', 'etc'))`

When calling this way I get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` when I hit the for loop. How do I fix this problem (and make sure the title/axes labelling and figure plotting works fine)?

Sample data from csv:

```
Species ,CerebellumSurfaceArea,CerebrumSurfaceArea,CerebellumVolume ,CerebrumVolume,Source,Taxon,,,,,,
Homo_sapiens,,,111.4,1088,MacLeod et al. (2003),Hominidae,,,,,,
Homo_sapiens,,,138.6,1387.1,,Hominidae,,,,,,
Homo_sapiens,,,132,1176.6,,Hominidae,,,,,,
Homo_sapiens,,,139.8,1264.5,,Hominidae,,,,,,
Homo_sapiens,1590,2038,,,Sereno et al. (2020),Hominidae,,,,,,
Homo_sapiens,1128,,,,Sultan and Braitenberg (1993),Hominidae,,,,,,
Pan_troglodytes,345.545,,52.1,383.22,Ashwell (2020),Hominidae,,,,,,
Pan_troglodytes,,,50.1,343.8,MacLeod et al. (2003),Hominidae,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are two issues, and they only occur when trying to send a single `tuple` to the function.

  1. `xy` should be a `tuple` of `tuples`

     - It should be similar to `(('CerebrumVolume', 'CerebellumVolume '), ('CerebrumVolume', 'CerebellumSurfaceArea'), ('CerebellumVolume ', 'CerebellumSurfaceArea'))`
     - You are giving it `('Cerebellum Surface Area', 'Cerebrum Volume')` which is not correctly unpacked.
     - `xy=(('CerebrumVolume', 'CerebellumVolume '),)` works for sending a single `tuple` to the function.
  2. When there is only one set of tuples to unpack, `plt.subplots` creates a single `axes` instead of an array of `axes`

     - Use `squeeze=False` so there will always be an array, even if there is only one `axes`, and then flatten the array with `axes.flatten()`.

```py
def create_plot(xy=var_combinations, logged=False):
    
    if not logged:
        fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(1, (len(xy)), figsize=(16, 5), squeeze=False)  # updated with squeeze=False
        axs1 = axs1.flatten()  # added

        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(xy):
            axs1[i].scatter(data[x], data[y], c=data.Taxon.map(colors), edgecolor='k')
            
            axs1[i].set(
                title=f'Primate {xy[i][0]} against\n{xy[i][1]}',
                xlabel=f'{xy[i][0]}',
                ylabel=f'{xy[i][1]}'
            )


data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=range(7))
col_names = data.columns.to_numpy()[[4, 3, 1]]
var_combinations = tuple(itertools.combinations(col_names, 2))
colors = {'Hominidae': 'tab:green'}

# fix the way a single tuple is passed to the function
create_plot(xy=(('CerebrumVolume', 'CerebellumVolume '),))
```

[image]